# markov definition by bounded measurable function

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I need to prove:

$$P(X_t|\mathcal{F}_s) = P(X_t|X_s) \Leftrightarrow E[f(X_t)|\mathcal{F}_s] = E[f(X_t)|X_s]$$

where

$$\mathcal{F}_s= \sigma(X_u,u\leq s)$$

(I have to prove that this two definition of marvok process are equal)

I can see that $$P(X_t|\mathcal{F}_s) = P(X_t|X_s) \rightarrow E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s] = E[X_t|X_s]$$

But I don't know how to continue from here.
Can you help me?

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: I have edited my question. Better now?

Comment: What does the hypothesis $P(X_t\mid\mathcal F_s)=P(X_t\mid X_s)$ mean to you?